# Compiling nonessential object files with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, compilation

Consider the following example

```
g++ a.o b.o c.o -o prog
```

If it is the case that `c.o` does not contribute any executable code to `prog`, nor are there any dependencies on `c.o` in any of the other files, will GCC yet include the contents of `c.o` in `prog`?

Said another way, aside from compilation time, what (if any) negative consequences can there be of compiling unnecessary files into an executable?

Thanks in advance; Cheers!

Comment: You could try linking with and without the extra library and see if the executable has the same size.

Comment: I don't know about GCC but MSVC will include the contents of all .obj files whether you reference them nor not, but it will include only the parts of .lib files that you reference. I'd expect GCC to be the same

Comment: The step described is commonly called "linking". The term "compiling" is normally used to describe the production of object files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any negative consequences except that your executable might be unnecessarily large.  The linker can probably dead strip unused code for you, and that will shrink things back down.  You can use some kind of object viewing tool (`otool`, `objdump`, `nm`, etc.) on the output executable to see if your program has extra symbols in it.

I'm using a Mac, so there will be some differences if you're using the standard set of gcc tools, but here's an example:

```
$ make
gcc -o app main.c file2.c
gcc -Wl,-dead_strip -o app_strip main.c file2.c
$ ls -l app*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 carl  staff  8744 Feb  6 20:05 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 carl  staff  8704 Feb  6 20:05 app_strip
```

I think in the non-Apple gcc world, you would pass `-Wl,--gc-sections` instead of the `-Wl,-dead_strip` in my example.  The size difference in the two executables you can see is due to the extra function being stripped:

```
$ nm app | cut -c 20- > app.txt
$ nm app_strip | cut -c 20- > app_strip.txt 
$ diff app.txt app_strip.txt 
8d7
< _function2
```

Answer (score 3):

`llvm` can eliminate dead code on linking step. It uses special linker `llvm-ld`.

Also, using `-fwhole` or `-ipo` (intel) will help to stripe dead symbols away.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it with some C code I'm currently using - I linked in an object that contained a method not (yet) used anywhere else in the program. The code was included in the resultant executable, checked by running `nm` against the elf file and observing that the method T was indeed there, even with -O2 and -O3 used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GCC will include all object files. With a very recent compiler (development version 4.5.0), you can use `-flto` (link-time optimization) to perform that.